# How to remove item from quote in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

During the checkout process I sometimes want to programmatically remove items from the session's quote. So I tried this code:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$all_quote_items = $quote->getAllItems();
foreach ($all_quote_items as $item) {
    $quote->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
}
```

However, after this loop the list of items in the `$quote` object is still the same, i.e. no items have been removed.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Using Magento 1.4.1.1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();        
foreach ($items as $item) 
{
   $itemId = $item->getItemId();
   $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
}
```

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/30113/

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to spot the problem.

Comment: Isn't this saving the cart on each iteration? Why would you do that? Remove the items in the iteration and save the cart outside of it.

Comment: @Renon how to use $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems(); this line in API ? Can I get Cart by cart  ID or customer ID using above codes ?

Comment: @SachinVairagi ... can you provide more info or sample code of what you are trying to do

Comment: require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.yxyshareoflove.stag-innov8te.com/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apitest', 'kavya@123');

$cartId = $_REQUEST['quote_id'];

$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart($cartId)->getItems();

if(count($items->getData())) {
 foreach ($items as $item) 
 {
    $itemId = $item->getItemId();
    $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
 }
 echo json_encode(array('status' => true ,
      'message' => '.'));
 }

Comment: Thanks much for your reply , please check my codes in above comment

Comment: @SachinVairagi ... you will need to use the magenot api since your code is hosted outside of magento... see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cartProduct.html

Comment: @RenonStewart - My products have custom option so I need to remove it using Item ID , can you please let me know if there is any way to do it ? It will be really helpful , thanks much.

Comment: @RenonStewart, shall we remove only specific product from cart and save it?
if (9 == $item->getProductId()) {
      $this->cart->removeItem($itemId);
      $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
      $quote->collectTotals()->save();
}

Answer (score 7):

In `Magento 1.7.0.0` version, you can use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate()->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar process while looking for items of a certain type, The logic I applied is:

```
$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote = $session->getQuote();

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cartItems = $cart->getItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item)
{
    $quote->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
}
```

Try the above and if that fails I would start dumping the quote objects out before and after this logic is executed to see what differences there are.

Comment: No, I copied your code 1:1 but the items are still in the $quote object after the loop.

Comment: ok, In the loop try adding: Zend_Debug::dump($quote->removeItem($item->getId())->save());die(); and let me know what this returns, It should either be NULL or some helpful data.

Comment: I used your code but it removed from a database table. But I want to remove from quote session after quote create

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code It will work

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $_item) {
    if ($_item->getProductId() == $productId) {
            $_item->isDeleted(true);
    //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('This product cannot be added to shopping cart.');
        }
    }
```