# Magento - Remove Item from Cart by Sku

Tags: magento, cart

i try to remove a product from Cart by Sku - is it possible?

I tried the following Code in cartcontroller.php but without success ....

I know it should work by ID but by Sku would be easier for me.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote = $session->getQuote();

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cartItems = $cart->getItems();

foreach($cartItems as $item) {
  if ($item->getSku() == promo){
    $quote->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
  }
}

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
$cart->init();
```

Answer (score 1):

Super close... get the product

```
if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == promo){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == 'promo') {
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();     
        break;
    }
}
```

See [How to remove item from quote in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057101/how-to-remove-item-from-quote-in-magento)

Comment: Thank you ! but its not running - no items will be removed - I think I´m on the wrong spot @ cartcontroller.php :-/

Comment: Where did you you add the code above (file name with path and method name?

Comment: app / code / core / Mage / Checkout / controllers / CartController.php - public function addAction() /// I tried it on different positions in Code without success :-/

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.p-lu.net/blog/2012/06/magento-abort-add-product-to-cart-programmatically-with-observer/ .. but using an observer would be the better way to accomplish this