# Magento - Option to Remove product from cart within product view page

Tags: php, magento, product

How do I add an option to remove a product from cart within product view page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an item from your cart by sku, you could create a controller with the below code

```
$sku = 'xyz';
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == $sku) {
        $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();     
        break;
    }
}
```

Then on your product view page you could create a ajax/button that post the sku you want to remove

See [Magento - Remove Item from Cart by Sku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191549/magento-remove-item-from-cart-by-sku)

Create: app/code/local/MagePal/DeleteCartItemBySku/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku after="Mage_Checkout">MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku</MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <models>
            <deletecartitembysku>
                <class>MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku_Model</class>
            </deletecartitembysku>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Create: app/code/local/MagePal/DeleteCartItemBySku/controllers/CartController.php

```
<?php   
  require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Checkout') . DS . 'CartController.php';
  //require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

  class MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
  {
    public function removeItemBySkuAction()
    {
        $sku = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
        $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
        $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();

        $found = false;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProduct()->getSku() == $sku) {
                $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();  
                $found = true;   
                break;
            }
        }

        $message = ($found) ? "Item {$sku} Removed" : "Item {$sku} Not Found";
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($message);

        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
  }
```

?>

Create: app/etc/modules/MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
           <modules>
                  <MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku>
                          <active>true</active>
                          <codePool>local</codePool>
                  </MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku>
           </modules>
    </config>
```

Then your ajax/button url :

> domain.com/checkout/cart/removeItemBySku/sku/xyz

Comment: I tried `<button class="form-button"  onclick="ajaxSubmit('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>/cart/removeItemBySku/sku/<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getSku()) ?>', this)"><span><?php echo $this->__('Remove From Cart') ?></span></button>` but the item is not getting removed. No error is shown. Thanks again.

Comment: I did check it and I got following error `http://www.domain.com/cart/removeItemBySku/sku/S738515 404 Not Found` I am working with simple products. Thanks

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
domain.com/cart/removeItemBySku/sku/S738515{ print_r('finish');}', this)`

Comment: While trying to access **domain.com/cart/removeItemBySku/sku/S738515** I am getting 404 not found magento page.

Firebug throws: `GET http://www.domain.com/cart/removeItemBySku/sku/S734319 404 Not Found 1.83s`

Comment: Yes, I have added and the module **MagePal_DeleteCartItemBySku** also shows up under **Advanced** as enabled in Magento Admin.

Comment: that worked like a charm. I am using A HREF attribute for it which is why it is taking to a blank page with the message **Item S738515 Removed** so is there any way to show the message in same place without having to redirect it to blank page? Million thanks.