# Submit form from http to https in Magento

Tags: php, magento, https, contacts

Currently I would like to redirect my contacts page from http to https.

I have managed to redirect this single page in the .htacces file by adding the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(contacts/.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code works for my domain.

The problem arrives when I click on submit. The form does not submit correct after the redirect is turned on. The message of the indexcontroller: "Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us" is not appearing and we do not receive an email. For now I turned redirecting off in the .htacces file.

The contacts.xml can be found in app/design/front/base/default/layout/contacts.xml
form.phtml is in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml

I copied these two files in to my template in case I need to change them. I tried my utter best to find something similair, but I could not find anything that works. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing this is being submitted via AJAX, what JS errors are you receiving? are you posting to https? what is the AJAX response if it is being sent?

Comment: Take a look at your contact form page source, your form action should still not be https so when submit your form it will redirect so you will not see the success msg. I think you could create a custom module that extend contact and use `<routers>` to make https

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey I do not how to post it to https... I used the RewriteUrl and this isnt working. I tried some things on the internet, but was scared I would break it so I changed everything back, because it did not work.(I do not have HTTPS installed on my test server)

Comment: @R.S do you have an example for me, so I can implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [Magento - Option to Remove product from cart within product view page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657565/magento-option-to-remove-product-from-cart-within-product-view-page/20658791#20658791)

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePal_Contacts>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </MagePal_Contacts>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <secure_url>
                <contact>/contact/</contact>
            </secure_url>
            <contacts>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MagePal_Contacts before="Mage_Contacts">MagePal_Contacts</MagePal_Contacts>
                    </modules>
                    <frontName>contacts</frontName>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>

       ...
```

Then change the form action to

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('', array('_secure'=>true)) . 'contacts/index/post' ?>" ...
```

or

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I did in the end was :

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(contacts/.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
in the .htacces 

and I changed the form to:  
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>" 

Thanks for you help too

Comment: How can I change the code of the form? Where is located?